# UML draw relations in classdiagram

Tags: uml, relationship, class-diagram

I'm trying to make a classdiagram, but i'm having a problem. I'm not sure if I have to draw this relationship.

Example:
Let's say I have three classes, A, B and C.
I have an instance of A and B.
In class A, I create an intance.
Now I pass C to B.

I'm sure I have to draw a relation between A and C.
Do I alse need to draw a relation between B and C?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Could you drawn something!? or could you explain me the followings sentences.
"I have an instance of A and B" where? who is their owner?
"I create an intance" an instance? An instance of what? where?
"Now I pass C to B" What?

Answer (score 0):

For class instances, there is UML's object diagram.